# Removing Multiple Files Ubuntu One

Tags: 12.04

I have 50 or 60 rogue files on Ubuntu One that I wish to delete.  Is there a way to do multiple files at once?

Using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key doesn't do the trick.  Additionally, when
trying to delete them one at a time, the delete option is hidden by the file below.

Comment: Which OS are you using, Windows or Ubuntu? In my case, I'm using Ubuntu and ctrl key is doing the trick perfectly.